# In C++, can a class include a pointer to the same class that's initialized in the constructor?

Tags: c++, pointers

I know a class can't have a member of the same class, e.g.

```
class Sample {
    int a = 0;
    Sample s; // error, object would need infinite size
};
```

But how come having a pointer is okay?

```
class Sample {
    // this compiles, but isn't it essentially the same
    // as above? 
    Sample() { s = new Sample(); } 
    int a = 0;
    Sample *s; 
};
```

Comment: You're looking at infinite allocations there.. The constructor initializes `s` by calling `Sample` constructor.. which initializes it's own `s`.. etc.. It's okay to have pointers to the same class sometimes.. such as in a `LinkedList`: `struct Node { Node* next; }`

Comment: It compiles, but that doesn't mean it's *okay*. With that code, you're going to have problems at runtime.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the code shown causes infinite recursion as soon as a `Sample` object is instantiated at runtime.

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried to run the program and I see the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer as a member is allowed because a pointer has a fixed size (4 bytes in a 32bit app, 8 bytes in a 64bit app), so the compiler can know the full size of `Sample` at compile time, it is not dependent on what the pointer is pointing at during runtime.

Creating an instance of `Sample` inside of the `Sample` constructor is not a syntax error, so the compiler allows it, but it will cause an infinite recursion loop at runtime.  So don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking very generally, the compiler is good at detecting problems with *types*, and bad at detecting problems with *values*.

In the latter case, sometimes that's because it can't (how can it know about things that happen ten years later?), and sometimes it's because it can't really be bothered (read: the standard doesn't require it to do mathematically difficult things, because that would be kind of mean).

In the first example, the recursive definition is a problem shown by the *types*. The compiler always knows that you've done it. In fact, there is physically no way for it to create a program matching that source code: no such thing can mathematically exist — it would go on forever.

But runtime indirection opens up new opportunities! A pointer doesn't *have* to point to anything. You could have left `s` uninitialised, or initialised it to `nullptr`, which would be fine. You could have left the choice up to an `if` with a `rand()` call. The best the compiler could do is analyse the constructor body to see whether you recursively instantiate a `Sample`. Ultimately, though, that's more effort than either the compiler or the standard are willing to put in<sup>1</sup>, so it becomes your problem.

In short: *that's just how it is*.

<sub><sup>1.</sup> What if your constructor body were in another translation unit? This time it's not, but C++ likes general rules…</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sample {
    int a = 0;
    Sample s; // error, object would need infinite size
};
```

The definition of `Sample` is unfinished at the place where you've declared `Sample s;`, therefore compiler doesn't know how much size it should be allocating ... it doesn't know what is `sizeof(Sample)`.

Pointer to itself i.e. `Sample *s;`, is standard size depending upon your target platform for which you compile your code.

Comment: Even if it did know, the answer would be "infinite", which is not very practical. The recursive definition is the true problem; not knowing the size is just a side effect. Although it's arguably up to interpretation, and definitely doesn't matter either way :)